# docker instruction format when having multipile parameters

Tags: docker, command-line-arguments

I'm new to docker, sorry if my question sounds dumb.

We know that many docker instruction e.g. RUN have following format when multipile parameters involved:

```
RUN ["executable", "param1", "param2"]
```

but why we don't make it as:

```
RUN ["executable", "param1 param2"]
```

Comment: It's the same as the difference between `ls -l /bin` and `ls '-l /bin'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executables typically access their arguments through "slot" numbers.  For example, if `executable` were a shell script, it might contain code like

```sh
arg1=$1
arg2=$2
```

In your first example, this would set `arg1` to `"param1"` and `arg2` to `"param2"`.  In your second example, however, they would be set to `"param1 param2"` and `""`, respectively.

You can see how this could affect the logic of the executable.